# My flat files should be UCS-2, but I can't import into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have twenty pipe-delimited text files that I would like to convert into a MySQL database. The manual that came with the data say

> Owing to the difficulty of displaying data for characters outside of
>   standard Latin Character Sets, all data is displayed using Unicode
>   (UCS-2) character encoding. All CSV files are structured using
>   commercial standards with the preferred format being pipe delimiter
>   (“|”) and carriage return + line feed (CRLF) as row terminators.

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.2.5 on Win 8.1, but the manual provides example SQL Server scripts to create the twenty tables. Here's one.

```
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[tbl_Company_Profile_Stocks] Script Date:
12/12/2007 08:42:05 ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Company_Profile_Stocks](
[BoardID] [int] NULL,
[BoardName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ClientCompanyID] [int] NULL,
[Ticker] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ISIN] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[OrgVisible] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)
```

Which I adjust as follows for MySQL.

```
/****** Object: Table dbo.tbl_Company_Profile_Stocks Script Date:
12/12/2007 08:42:05 ******/
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_Company_Profile_Stocks
(
BoardID int NULL,
BoardName varchar(255) NULL,
ClientCompanyID int NULL,
Ticker varchar(255) NULL,
ISIN varchar(255) NULL,
OrgVisible varchar(255) NULL
);
```

Because the manual says that the flat files are `UCS-2`, I set the `dbo` schema to `UCS-2 default collation` when I create it. This works fine AFAIK. It is the `LOAD INFILE` that fails. Because the data are pipe-delimited with `CRLF` line endings I try the following.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Richard/Dropbox/Research/BoardEx_data/unzipped/Company_Profile_Stocks20100416.csv'
INTO TABLE dbo.tbl_company_profile_stocks
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But in this case now rows are imported and the message is `0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0`. So I try `\n` line endings instead. This imports something, but my integer values become zeros and the text becomes very widely spaced. The message is `14121 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s): 1366 Incorrect integer value: <snip>  Records: 14121  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 28257`.

If I open the flat text file in Sublime Text 3, the Encoding Helper package suggests that the file has `UTF-16 LE with BOM` encoding. If I repeat the above with `UTF-16 default collation` when I create the `dbo` schema, then my results are the same.

How can I fix this? Encoding drives me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the main problem is that the LOAD DATA needs this clause (see [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)):

```
CHARACTER SET ucs2
```

In case that does not suffice, ...

- Can you get a hex dump of a little of the csv file?  I want to make sure it is really ucs2.  (ucs2 is very rare.  Usually text is transferred in utf8.)  If it looks readable when you paste text into this forum, then it is probably utf8 instead.
- There is no "dbo" ("database owner"), only database, in MySQL.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_Company_Profile_Stocks`
- (just a recommendation) Don't prefix table names with "tbl_"; it does more to clutter than to clarify.
- Provide a `PRIMARY KEY` for the table.

Comment: I think I need to close this question as too localized. Your `LOAD DATA` reference link shows that `LOAD DATA` does not support UCS-2. I can convert with Window's Command line `TYPE`, but then I still need to replace missing entries (i.e., `||`) with `\N`. I can do this in GnuWin32 `sed`, but this changes the encoding, creating more problems.

Comment: My real question should be "what *free* db can import SQL Server export files?" I don't care which one, as long as it's free.

Comment: Can you export it as something other than ucs2?  Such as utf8?

Comment: No, my advisor got these data years ago from a consulting gig and we can't go back to the well. That would be the best solution.

Comment: Is the entire file in ucs2?  That is, are simple English letters encoded as 2 bytes each?  If so, I wonder if there is a tool for converting the entire file from ucs2 to utf8.  I see a few Windows tools for such.

Answer (score 0):

@Rick James had the correct answer (i.e., set the encoding for `LOAD DATA` with the `CHARACTER SET` option). But in my case this didn't work [because MySQL doesn't support UCS-2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

> **Note**
>
> It is not possible to load data files that use the ucs2 character set.

Here are a few approaches that work here. In the end I went this SQLite rather than MySQL, but the last solution should work with MySQL, or any other DB that accepts flat files.

### SQLiteStudio

[SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/) was the easiest solution in this case. I prefer command line solutions, but the SQLiteStudio GUI accepts UCS-2 encoding and any delimiter. This keeps the data in UCS-2.

### Convert to ASCII in Windows command line

The easiest conversion to ASCII is in the Windows command line with `TYPE`.

```
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
    echo %%~nf
    type "%%~nf.csv" > "%%~nf.txt"
)
```

This may cause problems with special characters. In my case it left in single and double quotes that caused some problems with the SQLite import. This is the crudest approach.

### Convert to ASCII in Python

```
import codecs
import glob
import os

for fileOld in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    print 'Reading: %s' % fileOld
    fileNew = os.path.join('converted', fileOld)
    with codecs.open(fileOld, 'r', encoding='utf-16le') as old, codecs.open(fileNew, 'w', encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as new:
        print 'Writing: %s' % fileNew
        for line in old:
            new.write(line.replace("\'", '').replace('"', ''))
```

This is the most extensible approach and would allow you more precisely control which data you convert or retain.